# thread hangs in socketRead0 Java

Tags: java, sockets

Basically I am trying to download a HTML content of a webpage. The method is very simple

```
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder pageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            pageBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
```

But sometimes the program just hangs. I tried to debug and the thread stack trace tells me that it hangs when calling to method SocketRead0. I tried to set readtimeout for the connection but it does not work. Any ideas on how can I detect and get through the block of SocketRead0 ?

Edit: It seems that the problem I actually have is that getReponseCode implicitly calls some getInputStream and some read() methods and then hangs at readSocket0(). Is there anyway I can make sure that the call to getReponseCode() will be safe ?
Here is the stack trace of one thread hanging: Level 0 is the most recent call

```
thread 24stacktrace
        At 0level
        at method socketRead0
        at line -2
        At 1level
        at method read
        at line 129
        At 2level
        at method fill
        at line 218
        At 3level
        at method read1
        at line 258
        At 4level
        at method read
        at line 317
        At 5level
        at method parseHTTPHeader
        at line 687
        At 6level
        at method parseHTTP
        at line 632
        At 7level
        at method getInputStream
        at line 1200
        At 8level
        at method getResponseCode
        at line 379
        At 9level
        at method pushFinalRedirectedURL
        at line 132
        At 10level
        at method process
        at line 134
        At 11level
        at method run
        at line 40
```

Comment: as a side note, that code will potentially mangle the downloaded web page.  you should be using the charset of the webpage to correctly configure the InputStreamReader.

Answer (score 2):

socket read is a blocking operation. It will block until there is more data, the end of stream is reached or the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you also explain why setReadTimeOut() does not work. Since my thread hang means that there is still more data and it is not end of stream yet. Is it true to say that setReadTimeout() only works at the beginning. I mean if there is some data received at the start of read() within the timeout period then that is ok and even if there is no more data received, the thread just hangs there and waits. Is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your buffer has data to be read before you call the readline function. As Peter mentioned, SocketRead is a blocking function which means when it is called it will sit and wait until data is placed on the stream.

Try this:

```
while (in.ready()) {
    line = in.readLine();
    pageBuilder.append(line + "\n");
}
```

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is the link to the BufferedReader API.

Comment: Thanks russel, Now I seem to have problem with getReponseCode() instead. Please see my edit..

Comment: This would truncate the file (possibly to nothing) when ever there is no data ready at that moment. It would prevent blocking, but is likely to prevent loading the file as well.

Comment: @Peter You're right, his original code seemed to do the same so I thought it was a non issue. @User304462 I don't know the answer, the only thing I can suggest is to check the api and see if that helps. http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: So any suggestion about the truncation problem ? what is the best way to download the HTML content of a web page ?

Answer (score 2):

I have this error too and solved it. This problem occurs because sometimes the software try to open a connection to a server that don't send an response, but don't give a error too.

The software still waiting the server answer, but it never comes.

To avoid this, you need to use the `setConnectTimeout()` method, so if the server don't send a answer in determined time, the connection will be aborted.

[setConnectTimeout() reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to the previous answers about socket read being blocking:
if method `private native int socketRead0(FileDescriptor fd, byte b[], int off, int len, int timeout) throws IOException` 
gets the timeout 0 (the default), no timeout is used. Hence it can block instead of throwing an IOException.